# Isotope search not working on Ajax contents

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-isotope

I'm creating a search function using [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co) on my Ajax loading list items.

By following Isotope documentation and examples, I created below script-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var grid = null;

jQuery(function($) {

var qsRegex;

Isotope.Item.prototype._create = function() {
  // assign id, used for original-order sorting
  this.id = this.layout.itemGUID++;
  // transition objects
  this._transn = {
    ingProperties: {},
    clean: {},
    onEnd: {}
  };
  this.sortData = {};
};

Isotope.Item.prototype.layoutPosition = function() {
  this.emitEvent( 'layout', [ this ] );
};

Isotope.prototype.arrange = function( opts ) {
  // set any options pass
  this.option( opts );
  this._getIsInstant();
  // just filter
  this.filteredItems = this._filter( this.items );
  // flag for initalized
  this._isLayoutInited = true;
};

// layout mode that does not position items
Isotope.LayoutMode.create('none');

// --------------- //

// init Isotope
grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.element-item',
  layoutMode: 'none',
  filter: function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var searchResult = qsRegex ? $this.text().match( qsRegex ) : true;
    //var buttonResult = buttonFilter ? $this.is( buttonFilter ) : true;
    return searchResult;
    //return searchResult && buttonResult;
  }
});

// use value of search field to filter
var $quicksearch = $('#quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
  qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
  grid.isotope();
}) );

// debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
  var timeout;
  return function debounced() {
    if ( timeout ) {
      clearTimeout( timeout );
    }
    function delayed() {
      fn();
      timeout = null;
    }
    setTimeout( delayed, threshold || 100 );
  };
}
});
</script>
```

By default it's working as expected, and I added below lines after my ajax call for reloading (isotope) items after every Ajax call-

```
grid.isotope('reloadItems');
```

It's also working. And after that I tried below code to re filter items based on the search value, but not working.

```
grid.isotope( 'appended', '.element-item' );
```

After Ajax call, items are not updating based on the **search value**.
Let's say, I search with "york" then it's filtering existing items with "york". But after loading more items using Ajax, it's not filtering new items except I add or remove any value on the search field again.

What am I missing? Your help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to destroy and reinitialize isotope:

```
grid.isotope('destroy');
grid = $('.grid').isotope({....})
```

Comment: Not working, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isotope' of null

Comment: I tried to add before `grid.isotope('reloadItems');` and as well as your reply before `grid = $('.grid').isotope({....})`